# mean value of column entries when time condition is matched python

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, mean

I am searching for a code, which bins my huge dataset over a sepcific time.

Lets suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Time':['1582542231', '1582542231', '1582542232', '1582542232', '1582542232', '1582542232', '1582542232', '1582542233', '1582542233', '1582542233'], 'Value':[20, 21, 19, 19, 18, 15, 16, 11, 4, 15], 'blabla':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         Time  Value  blabla
0  1582542231     20     1
1  1582542231     21     2
2  1582542232     19     3
3  1582542232     19     4
4  1582542232     18     5
5  1582542232     15     6
6  1582542232     16     7
7  1582542233     11     8
8  1582542233      4     9
9  1582542233     15     10
```

Now I would like to build a new column 'mean' or replace the columns with the average value of column 'Value' and 'blabla' for the same timestamp 'Time'

This means the following output:

```
         Time  Value  blabla
0  1582542231   20.5     1.5
1  1582542232   17.4     5
2  1582542233     10     9
```

The difficulty is that the dataframe is over thousands of seconds long and I do not know how to build a proper condition to select the data, because the number of timestamp entries varies. Sometimes I have 100 entries for the same timestamp (e.g. 1582542231) and sometimes I have 150 entries for another timestamp.

I tried a lot of things with groupby, but without any satisfactory solution. Hope I  explained the problem properly, because English is not my mother tongue.

Greets :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I found out how to code it. If anybody in future is interested in, here is the code:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],unit='s')
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
df_group = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Time', freq='1s'))['Value', 'blabla'].agg('mean')
```

Yields to:

```
                     Value  blabla
Time                              
2020-02-24 11:03:51   20.5     1.5
2020-02-24 11:03:52   17.4     5.0
2020-02-24 11:03:53   10.0     9.0
```